# C++ function not getting called

Tags: c++

I have a function that takes 2d-vector and outputs a 2d-vector. For some reason, the function is not getting called.
Here is the link to reproduce the issue: [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AWhWz8pBGR_zYgimDzNS3MjPLtvPVFJQ?usp=sharing).
In the link to check for correctness, I have added another code that uses the exact same function but doesn't take a 2d-vector array as an argument instead it runs on static input.
**mycode.cpp:**

```
#include <vector>
#include "geomutils.h"
#include "mycode.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector< vector<double> > customComputeConvexHull(vector< vector<double> > i_matrix){
  cout <<"\nDone1.1";
  Polygon custompts, customhull;
  for (int r = 0; r < i_matrix.size(); r++){
    custompts.push_back(Point(i_matrix[r][0], i_matrix[r][1]));
  }
  computeConvexHull(custompts, customhull);
  // vector< vector<double> > res;
  vector<vector<double>> res( customhull.size() , vector<double> (2));
  for(int i = 0;i < customhull.size();i ++) {
        res[i][0] = customhull[i].x;
        res[i][1] = customhull[i].y;
  }
  return res;
}

void print_polygon(Polygon &h, int name){
    std::cout << "\nHull in "<< name << ": \n"<<"[";
    for(int i = 0;i < h.size();i ++) {
        std::cout << "("<< h[i].x<< ", "<< h[i].y<<"), ";
    }
    std::cout <<"]\n";
}

void get_convex_hull_custom(){
    Polygon custompts;
    Polygon customhull;
    custompts.push_back(Point(0,0));
    custompts.push_back(Point(4.58,7.14));
    custompts.push_back(Point(0,7.14));
    computeConvexHull(custompts, customhull);
    print_polygon(customhull, -99999);
}


int main()
{
    // Create an empty vector
    vector< vector<double> > mat,mat2;
    
    vector<double> myRow1(0,0);
    mat.push_back(myRow1);

    vector<double> myRow2(7.61,9.48);
    mat.push_back(myRow2);
    
    vector<double> myRow3(0,9.48);
    mat.push_back(myRow3);
    cout <<"Done1\n";

    get_convex_hull_custom();

    mat2 = customComputeConvexHull(mat);
    cout <<"Done2";

    return 0;
}
```

**mycode.h:**

```
#ifndef _code
#define _code

#include <vector>

std::vector< std::vector<double> > customComputeConvexHull (std::vector< std::vector<double> > i_matrix);

#endif
```

**geomutils.cpp:**

```
#include "geomutils.h"

#include <iostream>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/boost_tuple.hpp>

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOOST_TUPLE_CS(cs::cartesian)


void computeConvexHull(Polygon &pts, Polygon &chull) {
    chull.clear();
    if(pts.size() == 1) {
        chull.push_back(pts[0]);
        chull.push_back(pts[0]);
        return;
    } else if(pts.size() == 2) {
        chull.push_back(pts[0]);
        chull.push_back(pts[1]);
        chull.push_back(pts[0]);
        return;
    }

    typedef boost::tuple<double, double> point;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::multi_point<point> mpoints;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point> polygon;

    mpoints mpts;

    for(int i = 0;i < pts.size();i ++) {
        boost::geometry::append(mpts,point(pts[i].x,pts[i].y));
    }
    polygon hull;

    // Polygon is closed
    boost::geometry::convex_hull(mpts, hull);
    for(auto pt : hull.outer()) {
        chull.push_back(Point(pt.get<0>(), pt.get<1>()));
    }
}
```

**geomutils.h:**

```
#ifndef GEOMUTILS_H
#define GEOMUTILS_H

#include <vector>

struct Point {
    double x,y;

    Point(){}
    Point(double x, double y):x(x),y(y){}
};

typedef std::vector<Point> Polygon;

void computeConvexHull(Polygon &pts, Polygon &chull);

#endif // GEOMUTILS_H
```

When I compile the code and try to run it.
Only `Done1` gets printed on the console. It neither gives any error nor any message.
**Output:**

```
Done1

Hull in -99999: 
[(0, 0), (0, 7.14), (4.58, 7.14), (0, 0), ]
```

Comment: You allocate res but empty. Then indexing causes segfault, in both dimensions. Either give size to constructor or resize after inigialization, for both dimensions.

Comment: If that's the issue why doesn't `Done1.1` gets printed on the console? The cout statement is at the top of the function?

Comment: Std::endl flushes. You did not flush hence it did not print.

Comment: @Coolboy I meant that we cannot compile your code to help you... anyway it's evident that you are settings elements on res vector which are not present and this make the program to throw an exception (it crashes anyway) and this is why your code is not working. You have to use push_back on res vector to populate it. The cout is not  printed because I think the output is not flushed (this depends on the OS)

Comment: I have added all the files necessary for the code to compile. These are same files present in `Topomap-aniket/bindings` directory in the repo that is getting cloned in code link provided in the question. It uses one external library `boost`.

Comment: *" Only `Done1` gets printed on the console."* -- Only. So there is no `Done2`? Didn't you find that suspicious? If the function was not being called, you should have seen `Done2`. And yet, you did not. It is important to notice and consider details like these when debugging! Then once you've deduced that there is a crash, switch from `cout` to `cerr`. There is a reason the error stream is not buffered. (Unbuffered means more reliable output if the program crashes.)

Comment: `computeConvexHull` is a different function defined inside `geomutils.cpp`. How is this recursive? The function name is different for both of them?

Comment: You are describing things which we cannot see. Please make a MRE, doing that alone will be a way of debugging which will be very enlightening for you.

Comment: I updated the question with code for `geomutils.cpp` some time ago. I can see the code in question. Is it not visible?

Comment: I realize that the code might throw some warnings w.r.t signed comparisons. But the code in the function `computeConvexHull` is correct. I have updated the code in question which takes static input and passes it to the function and indeed I do get an `output`. Can you elaborate on SegFaults and what is causing them and how to fix it?

Comment: `vector<double> myRow1(0,0);` is an empty vector. `vector<double> myRow2(7.61,9.48);` has seven elements, all of which are `9.48`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some issue on your code. First of all in `main` to correctly initialize the vector you have to use the `{}` syntax. Further in `customComputeConvexHull` you are setting values inside the `res` vector which are not yet present. You have to use `push_back` to populate `res`. Below a version of your code which works (I put everything into one `cpp` file for semplicity.

```
#include <vector>
//#include "geomutils.h"
//#include "mycode.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/boost_tuple.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct Point {
    double x, y;

    Point() {}
    Point(double x, double y) :x(x), y(y) {}
};

typedef std::vector<Point> Polygon;

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOOST_TUPLE_CS(cs::cartesian);


void computeConvexHull(Polygon& pts, Polygon& chull) {
    chull.clear();
    if (pts.size() == 1) {
        chull.push_back(pts[0]);
        chull.push_back(pts[0]);
        return;
    }
    else if (pts.size() == 2) {
        chull.push_back(pts[0]);
        chull.push_back(pts[1]);
        chull.push_back(pts[0]);
        return;
    }

    typedef boost::tuple<double, double> point;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::multi_point<point> mpoints;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point> polygon;

    mpoints mpts;

    for (int i = 0; i < pts.size(); i++) {
        boost::geometry::append(mpts, point(pts[i].x, pts[i].y));
    }
    polygon hull;

    // Polygon is closed
    boost::geometry::convex_hull(mpts, hull);
    for (auto pt : hull.outer()) {
        chull.push_back(Point(pt.get<0>(), pt.get<1>()));
    }
}

vector< vector<double> > customComputeConvexHull(vector< vector<double> > i_matrix) {
    cout << "\nDone1.1";
    Polygon custompts, customhull;
    for (int r = 0; r < i_matrix.size(); r++) {
        custompts.push_back(Point(i_matrix[r][0], i_matrix[r][1]));
    }
    computeConvexHull(custompts, customhull);
    vector< vector<double> > res;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        vector<double> v1{ customhull[i].x,  customhull[i].y };
        res.push_back(v1);
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    // Create an empty vector
    vector< vector<double> > mat, mat2;

    vector<double> myRow1{0, 0};
    mat.push_back(myRow1);

    vector<double> myRow2{ 7.61, 9.48 };
    mat.push_back(myRow2);

    vector<double> myRow3{ 0, 9.48 };
    mat.push_back(myRow3);
    cout << "Done1";

    mat2 = customComputeConvexHull(mat);
    cout << "Done2";

    return 0;
}
```